# PostgreSQL 9.6 dblink extension not working properly?

Tags: dblink, postgresql-9.6

I have strange problems with parallel run of tasks using dblink extension on PostgreSQL 9.6.1. Looks like extension in some cases cannot recognize that task in connection already ended and still waits for result. Therefore programs which used to run absolutely perfectly on PG 9.5 sometimes keep hanging indefinitely on PG 9.6.

Procedure:

- connection is opened using "perform dblink_connect"
- query is send using 'dblink_send_query"
- other tasks are send to different connections
- program takes first connection and issues "dblink_get_result" and waits for output
- after it takes second connection etc. - some of those connections already ended so they should give result immediately after start of "dblink_get_result" but in some cases it does not work on PG 9.6 and check just hangs...

Are there some changes in dblink behavior in PG 9.6 I am not aware of?